# cannot make excel visible on server. Visible always equals false

Tags: c#, excel, interop, visible

All i am trying to do is set my instance of excel to visible.

1 line of code xlApp.Visible = true;

works as expected running visual Studio development server. However when I run it on the local IIS server and on my Windows 2008 test server that line of code never sets xlApp.Visible to true.  It remains false.  I can put a breakpoint on the one line of code and step through it and it stays false.  No errors, no warnings nothing.

Been stuck for 3 days.  Just can't figure it out.  Maybe something with IIS since it occurs on my local IIS server and on my test server.

Comment: I hate when people answer this way, but pay heed: Microsoft does not recommend or support server-side automation of Office.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 might be able to shed some light, but in general, it is a hard road ahead.

Comment: Here is a thread (from 2005) that has some suggestions: http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=93872